# MPMusicPlayerController Speed Adjustment

Tags: iphone, xcode, audio

HI,

Is there any way to adjust the speed of the song being played by the MPMusicPlayerController?

I've searched everywhere but didn't find anything useful. If there is no way to do it where can I find an example which does it with other components? Some say OpenAL, but I can't find any clear way to use the iPod library with this and change the speed of the song...

Mainly the thing I need is:

1. The user chooses a song from the iPod library trough MPMusicPlayerController
2. You have 2 buttons: Slow Down & Speed Up

If the user presses "Slow Down" the speed of the song is slowed down by lets say 5% or something. "Speed Up" visa-versa.

I really hope someone can help me with this!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

You could do this as of iOS 3.2 and later -

```
[musicPlayer play];
[musicPlayer setCurrentPlaybackRate:2.0];
```

Ref: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMediaPlayback_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfp/MPMediaPlayback/currentPlaybackRate

Comment: This documentation no longer mentions the currentPlaybackRate. I can't find it anywhere, I wonder if its going to be deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use AVAudioPlayer and AVPlayer for the above purpose.
They have a rate property which can set the speed of the song.

```
[AVPlayer setRate:1.25];  // 25% faster
```

However, AVPlayer cannot change the speed by 5% but 25% and AVAudioPlayer works for iOS 5 and above.
If you wish to go for other alternative then Dirac is the best option. Try [DIRAC 3 LE](http://dirac.dspdimension.com/Dirac3_Technology_Home_Page/Dirac3_Technology.html) which is free.

Use this [Link](http://purplelilgirl.tumblr.com/post/3915153445/tutorial-other-ways-to-chipmunkify-your-voice) to get an idea on how to use Dirac. For more information, let me know.

@girish_vr

Answer (score -1):

No, you can't do this using only the MPMusicPlayerController.

If you don't mind the pitch going up and down proportional to the speed changes, then you can use the OpenAL resampler after converting your sound file to raw PCM sample files or buffers.

If you don't want the pitch to change, what you are looking for is DSP time pitch stretching/modification/correction techniques.  OpenAL can't do this, but there are commercial DSP libraries (DIRAC may be one) available that can do this on iOS.  You could also try writing your own phase vocoder, but this is non-trivial digital signal processing code.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I already saw DIRAC but the commercial license costs almost 10k... So for a small and funny app it's way too expensive. But how does, for example, mix meister and Tap DJ do their scratching?